# Issue with SharePoint Migration Assessment Tool: Failing in validation check

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration, sharepointmigrationtool

We are trying to run SharePoint Migration Assessment tool given by microsoft, but it is failing in pre validation with below errors.

[image]

Can someone please guide on this?

Comment: Is the user account you are using farm admin? Make sure you are running the tool using farm admin account.

Comment: @Gift, what's your status, did you try `SharePoint Migration Tool`instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that `SharePoint Migration Tool` (SPMT) also includes an [assessment tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/spmt-scan)? Because this is a more modern tool from Microsoft than the "old" `SharePoint Migration Assessment Tool` (SMAT).

[image: SPMT]

In your case, the issue is that the user which start the executable is not a SharePoint administrator. You can "run as different user" the program with *shift + right click* and enter the login/password of the SharePoint farm admin.

[image: run as]